# how can i know if connection is safe true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, nosql

i made many times questions about connections on mongodb, i cant understand many things yet, but i try...

with this connection...

```
db.collection('usuarios').insert(campos,{safe:true}, function(err, result)
```

i get a safe connection.... but mongodb pull me this warning

```
========================================================================================
=  Please ensure that you set the default safe variable to one of the                  =
=   allowed values of [true | false | {j:true} | {w:n, wtimeout:n} | {fsync:true}]     =
=   the default value is false which means the driver receives does                    =
=   return the information of the success/error of the insert/update/remove            =
=                                                                                      =
=   ex: new Db(new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:true})                            =
=                                                                                      =
=   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command                           =
=                                                                                      =
=  The default of false will change to true in the near future                         =
=                                                                                      =
=  This message will disappear when the default safe is set on the driver Db           =
========================================================================================
```

so i try this way...

```
var db = mongo.db("root:toor@127.0.0.1:27017/cordoba",{safe:true});
db.collection('usuarios').insert(campos,{new:true}, function(err, result)
```

but im not sure if this is a safe:true connection so i put like this

```
var db = mongo.db("root:toor@127.0.0.1:27017/cordoba",{safe:true});
    db.collection('usuarios').insert(campos,{safe:true},{new:true}, function(err, result)
```

may be that way is safe:true but when i put safe:true before new:true mongodb returns me the old var, so i put safe:true after new:true

```
var db = mongo.db("root:toor@127.0.0.1:27017/cordoba",{safe:true});
    db.collection('usuarios').insert(campos,{new:true},{safe:true}, function(err, result)
```

and works right but im not sure if it is safe:true, so i try  put safe:true in new:true object like this

```
var db = mongo.db("root:toor@127.0.0.1:27017/cordoba",{safe:true});
        db.collection('usuarios').insert(campos,{new:true,safe:true},function(err, result)
```

i thought that mongdb freaks out! but nothing... no error no nothing .... so i dont know how can i know when mongodb is using safe:true or not safe:true...

how can i know that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the api is no longer `{safe: true}` but `{w: 1}` http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html

```
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', {w: 1})
```

`{safe: true}` will still work, but it's deprecated. if you set it at the DB level, you don't need to set it at the `collection.insert()` level.

the api signature for insert is `insert(docs[, options][, callback])`, so you should only have one options object.

also, there is no `{new: true}` options for `collection.insert`.

so basically, you don't need to set any options (on insert).